# Servlet throw Stackoverflowerror with Apache FOP

Tags: java, xml, servlets, pdf, apache-fop

I'm trying to create a XML file and from this and a XSL file a new PDF should be created. The problem is that yesterday everything worked fine.
Today I rerun the program and all of a sudden it crashes everytime I want to create the PDF. 
 
I'm using Apache FOP 9.5 to create the PDF and the last lines I see in the log before the error occures are

> Blockquote 
>   **javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception**
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:314)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at com.t_systems.pif_frontend.tools.UTF8Filter.doFilter(UTF8Filter.java:164)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   **Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError**

After that line I'm getting a lot of lines like this:

> Blockquote 
>  at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:709)
>       at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:421)
>       at org.apache.fop.fo.properties.PercentLength.toString(PercentLength.java:121)
>       at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2981)
>       at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:265)
>       at org.apache.fop.fo.flow.table.TableColumn.toString(TableColumn.java:233)
>       at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2981)
>       at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:265)
>       at org.apache.fop.datatypes.LengthBase.toString(LengthBase.java:135)
>       at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2981)
>       at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:265)
>       at org.apache.fop.fo.properties.PercentLength.toString(PercentLength.java:121)
>       at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2981)
>       at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:265)
>       at org.apache.fop.fo.flow.table.TableColumn.toString(TableColumn.java:233)

These lines repeat several times.
From my logging I see that the program reaches this code section:

```
Fop fop;
        fop = FopFactory.newInstance().newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, pdf);
        logger.debug("FactoryManager created");
        Source xml = new StreamSource(xmlFile);
        Source xsl = new StreamSource(xslFile);
        logger.debug("StreamSources created");
        Result sax = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
        logger.debug("Result created");
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(xsl);
        logger.debug("Tranformator created"); //This is the last line that gets printed before the crashing occures
        transformer.transform(xml, sax);
        logger.debug("Transformation done"); //This line is not printed out
```

I think that the

> transformer.transform(xml, sax);

line is causing the error but it worked fine several days before without any changes.
 Has anybody an idea what migth be the problem here? I've seen some people writing about a never ending recursive call but that's not the case here because I only call the function once and based on the result I'm forwarding to another page.

Answer (score 2):

okay so the answear seems to be a missing log4j.properties file.

In the project this file went missing and thats what causes the crashes. After adding the properties file everything is working fine.

Comment: You can accept your own answer; you won't get reputation points, but other users will be able to see that the question has a correct answer.

Comment: This is so weird. Have you got some reference or explanation?